# Linking C-Library libcypher-parser to golang project

Tags: go, ffi, cgo

So I am trying to link the [libcypher-parser](https://github.com/cleishm/libcypher-parser) library to my local golang project but so far, when i'm trying to build my code I am getting `./cypher-test.go:22:35: could not determine kind of name for C.cypher_parse`.  I'm not making progress with this, I hope someone can help me out with this.

I am using Linux and I installed the library as instructed:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cleishm/libcypher-parser.git
$ cd libcypher-parser
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make clean check
$ sudo make install
```

So far so good.

> libcypher-parser.a
> libcypher-parser.so
> libcypher-parser.so.11.0.0
> libcypher-parser.la
> libcypher-parser.so.11
> pkgconfig/

can now be found in `/usr/local/lib` and

> cypher-parser.h

can be found in `/usr/local/include`

As far as I understand it from their README.md i should be able to link the installed library and obtain the required flags via `pkg-config --libs libcypher-parser`. This was complaining about a missing `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` so i set it to `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`. Now `pkg-config --libs libcypher-parser` gave me the following:

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lcypher-parser
```

Furthermore i set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

When I run the following code:

```
package main

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lcypher-parser -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib
// #include <cypher-parser.h>
// #include <errno.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
import "C"

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    options := C.CYPHER_PARSE_ONLY_STATEMENTS
    fmt.Println(options)
    cypher_parse_result_t * result = C.cypher_parse("MATCH (n) RETURN n", nil, nil, options)
}
```

it gives me `./cypher-test.go:22:35: could not determine kind of name for C.cypher_parse`

I tried many different paths and combinations for the CFLAG and LDFLAGS but i wasn't able to link the library/use the function. It's always the same outcome. Just some examples I've tried:

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/include
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lcypher-parser -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I/usr/local/lib
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib -lcypher-parser -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib

// #cgo CFLAGS: -I../libcypher-parser/lib/src
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L../libcypher-parser/lib/ -lcypher-parser -Wl,-rpath=../libcypher-parser/lib
```

(The last one was a desperate try to link inside the checked out repository)

Does anyone have an idea what I might be missing ? It's my first time trying to link a c-library in go - i hope the catch is not too obvious :)

Comment: `cypher_parse` is not a function but a macro. Either create a helper C function to invoke it or use `cypher_uparse` instead.

Comment: What rustyx said—[see](https://github.com/cleishm/libcypher-parser/blob/f5b240d2d3ff42be218bf122c84250bcea1d236f/lib/src/cypher-parser.h.in#L5645). The "trick" is that macros are expanded by the preprocessor and do not exist at the compilation phase (let alone linkage), and by the time your Go code referring to that "C" pseudo-package gets compiled, the compilation of the supporting C code generated by `cgo` (and made available as that "C" pseudo-package) _has already finished,_ and all macros got expanded. Well, and the Go compiler could not make use of them anyway.

Comment: Okay, tanks for the clearification. So the example which is listed on https://github.com/cleishm/libcypher-parser is only valid for c integrations when the library is not linked as a compiled installed library but rather when the repository is checked out and linked. In other words macros only work for uncompiled code and only withing C (or at least not go) integrations. did I get this right ?

Comment: Not quite. Macros are placed in so-called "header files"—those files which name usually ends in ".h" and which contain definition of types, macros and _declarations_ of functions. These files provided along with compiled libraries are `#include`d in the source code which intends to use the library, and that forces the proprocessor to physically "paste" the contents of the header—replacing the include directive. Then any macros are expanded. The resulting wall of text is then processed by the C compiler.

Comment: Contrary to that, Go code is compiled by Go compiler, and _bits_ of C code extracted from the definitions embedded into Go files get processed by the C compiler and then the result is analyzed by the `cgo` machinery to create shim Go types and function definitions which your code sees through that "C" pseudopackage. Since macros are in a sense intangible as they evaporate during the compilation, there is no easy way for Go and `cgo` to make use of them.

Comment: Note that you can declare a helper function which makes use of a macro either in the C code included in a `cgo` comment or in a plain C file in your Go package: when `cgo` is used, `go build` also compiles and links in all the C and C++ source code files found in the package directory. That's what rustyx suggested. Please consult the `cgo` docs. Since this C code is compiled by a C compiler it will have no problem using a macro—provided the necessary header file is included.